# mixing aggregate and top 1 in one query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

in the select below I have **2 aggregate** and **5 top 1** field

```
select *
from (
       select sum(case when field2 = 1 then 1 end) over (partition by field0) as field5,
              max(case when field3 = 1 then field4 end) over (partition by field0) as field6,
              -- above is 2 aggregates

              -- below is select 5 fields based on top 1 order by desc
              row_number() over (partition by field0 order by field1 desc) as rowNum
              field0,
              field1,
              field2,
              field3,
              field4
       from table1
        --in my case i'm doing an innser join on field0 on an inserted table from a trigger
  ) x
-- below is the top 1 related filter
where x.rowNum = 1
```

is there a better way to write this? (meaning faster in the execution plan and/or better syntax)

current section of the execution plan
[image: current section of the execution plan]

Comment: what you mean `5 top 1`?  show us the current execution plan? Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza field0,1,2,3,4 are top 1 based on the row number (order by desc)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i added the execution plan

Comment: The portion of the execution plan in your image only accounts for 8% of the resource cost.   I'd say that the bottleneck probably lies in some other part of the plan.

Comment: Yes, I was about to say the picture was incomplete because only 8% is visible.

Comment: this select is actually being used in a bigger one, it is a left join

Comment: At first look I dont see any room from improvement, maybe if you include some data and desire output we can see anything else. Again perfomance question should include table size, index and current time perfomance.

Comment: You want optimize `AB` or `B` ? dont make sense you ask for `B` and show us `AB` plan :(

Answer (score 0):

This should be a bit optimized:

```
select field0,
    field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    field4,
    field5,
    field6
from (
    select field0,
        sum(case when field2 = 1 then 1 end) as field5,
        max(case when field3 = 1 then field4 end) as field6,
    from table1
    group by field0
) t1
cross apply
(
    select top 1 field1,
        field2,
        field3,
        field4
    from table1 t2
    where t2.field0 = t1.field0
    order by field1 desc
) ca
```